# randomForest chooses regression instead of classification

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm using the [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) package in R and using the iris data, the random forest generated is a classification but when I use a dataset with around 700 features (the features are each pixel in a 28x28 pixel image) and the label column is named `label`, the `randomForest` generated is regression. I'm using the following line:

```
rf <- randomForest(label ~ ., data=train)
```

How come regression is used instead of classification? The data is read in through `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 11):

randomForest will default to classification or regression depending on the class of the variable. So if you type

```
class(iris$Species)
```

you will see that it is a factor. 'label' in your code, is most likely numeric, so randomForest defaults to regression. You will need to convert it to a factor for classification. You can convert it or read it in as a factor by setting colClasses in read.table.

Answer (score 4):

Most often this is because you did not tell R that label is a categorical variable.  The `read.csv` function tries to guess what type to use for each column and if it looks like a numeric column then that is what it will use.  You can check how R stores the variable using the `str` function.  You can force `read.csv` to read the variable as a factor (or numeric, or ...) using the `colClasses` argument.  Or you can change labels to a factor after reading it in using the `factor` function.

If this is not the case then we need more information about your data.  The results from running `str` on your data frame would probably be useful.